# Moving db to remote server slows down join queries

Tags: mysql, rackspace

We just moved our db off the actual server box to a mysql 5.6 rackspace cloud instance (on the same net as the server)

In general this had a very positive performance effect.

However this query has slowed down from milliseconds to about 10 minutes...

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `orders`
LEFT JOIN jobs
  ON jobs.order_id = orders.id
  AND (original_job_id IS NULL)
WHERE `orders`.`administrator_id` = 2
  AND (orders.order_billing_time > '2001-01-01 06:00:00')`
```

The jobs table is very large, but similar and much more complex queries on the job table with joins, etc, are running faster.

Comment: Check the Query Execution Plan for the query on the remote and the local server. Maybe you're missing an index or something...

Comment: sql ain't my thing but I will look into it... all we did was copy the original db (hosted on our server) to the new db server, would that not copy all the indexes?

Comment: Copy, how? Did you copy the database files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the amount of memory the same size on the new server? If the jobs table is that large you may be running out and using swap space instead. Try increasing the memory size of the database instance.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks a lot Ethan!